# Exception when updating Hibernate object whose table has a history trigger tied to it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, triggers

I have a table Schools, with and update trigger `SchoolsHistory`.  The trigger works fine when I update via simple SQL statement.  When Hibernate (via Spring) updates the object, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation:   
could not insert: [...]; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [the sql...]; SQL    
state [null]; error code [0]; The statement must be executed before any
results     can be obtained.; nested exception is
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement must be
executed     before any results can be obtained.
```

The exception does not appear when I disable the trigger.  Also, the trigger happens on WebSphere, but not on Tomcat, so possibly something to do with the clusters, etc. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong with the trigger code. If you say that manually entering SQL in the editor for `insert` statement and it works means that Hibernate uses different `insert` statement. You can use Hibernate property `show_sql`:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

to see the difference between sql statements you use and Hibernate produce. One thing is important the hibernate use `id` column for setting the primary key when inserted a new record. Check the trigger code or turn off triggers if it could resolve the issue.

Comment: no, the trigger works fine, i changed my code in the app to do an sql insert/update and everthing including the trigger worked fine.  it fails when i use saveOrUpdate(obj)...

Comment: Why do you use it, if the id is empty then you need to `save` otherwise `update`.

Comment: its a utility method that does exactly that - saves if id is empty, updates if id is not empty - thats not the issue.  I get the same exception when explicitly calling save(obj).

Comment: What a jdbc code do you execute, it's not seen from your question.

Comment: its business code that I cant put online, trust me the sql is fine.